# NPM Install and Save Local Relative Path

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm trying to `npm install` a local `.tgz` package for distributing shared Angular components.

```
npm install ./../@company/my-package-0.10.0.tgz --save
```

The problem is the above code saves the full pathname in the `package.json`.

E.g.

```
"@company/package": "file:///C:\\...\\my-package-0.10.0.tgz"
```

This poses an issue with source control for fellow developers on my team, as we don't all have the source installed in an identical location.

How can I make `npm` save the relative file path within `package.json` with the `npm install` command? I don't want to have to alter the `package.json` file manually and run a full npm install each time I update the component package.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this is the end result that I want:

install:

`npm install ./../@company/my-package-0.10.0.tgz --save`

package.json:

`"@company/package": file:./../@company/my-package-0.10.0.tgz`

Comment: I'd also like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this with NPM 6.14.15. I suspect that this issue has been fixed by Node/NPM since this issue was asked 5 years ago :)